# Convert Amount into Words in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to a convert Rupees amount into words in SQL

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below but there is a catch the maximum it can show is one hundred million

```
  create or replace function spell_number(p_number number) return varchar2 is
  l_str varchar2(200);
  begin
  l_str := to_char(to_timestamp(lpad(nvl(trunc(p_number), 0) , 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'FFSP');
 return l_str;
 end;

with data as (select 99999998  currency from dual)
SELECT spell_number(currency)
from data
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to convert the number to a Julian date, and then to convert that back to a string with the words spelled out. Alas, this will only work in English, and it won't use Indian units like Lakh and Crore.

```
with
  inputs as (select '₹1,53,050' as price_in_rupees from dual)
select price_in_rupees,
       initcap(to_char(to_date(to_number(price_in_rupees, 'L99,99,99,999',
               'nls_currency=₹'), 'J'), 'JSP')) || ' Indian Rupees'
       as price_spelled_out
from   inputs
;

PRICE_IN_RUPEES PRICE_SPELLED_OUT
--------------- ----------------------------------------------------
₹1,53,050       One Hundred Fifty-Three Thousand Fifty Indian Rupees
```